# "." syntax error comes while i am doing inner join

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
const char *sqlStatement = "select s.id, s.no, s.sc p.na from table1 s inner join table2 p on p.id = s.id";
```

It gives `an error that near ".": syntax error`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings need to be in quotes.

```
const char *sqlStatement = "select s.id, s.no, s.sc, p.na from table1 s inner join table2 p on p.id = s.id";
```

Answer (score 1):

missing comma 
"select s.id, s.no, s.sc, p.na...